# Timer task is misbehaving in service

Tags: android, timertask

I am using timer task  to execute asynctask at fixed interval of time the time five minutes. but timer task sometimes started to misbehave like it doesn't get
at fixed delay in fact it get executed after 10  minutes twice instead of getting every 5 minute why so?

Here is my code

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
            mytimer Mytimer = new mytimer();

            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Mytimer, 300000, 300000);


class Mytimer extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new DetailPosition().execute();
        }
    }
```

So  help me in this

Comment: Post your code.  And for starters, you should probably not be using `Timer` at all.  The "Android way" to do things at intervals is via `Handler#postDelayed(...)`.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Add Code in question please check it out..

Comment: I like the word 'misbehaving' :)

Comment: [The docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) state that "The task instance must be created on the UI thread" and "`execute(Params...)` must be invoked on the UI thread."  You're breaking both of those rules.  Ditch the `Timer` and use a `Handler`.

Answer (score 2):

If the timer task is scheduled on a thread pool where all the threads are in use, then it will have to wait for one to become available before running your task.

Consider the following -

```
 ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();    
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {Thread.sleep(500); System.out.println(new Date());}, 0, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Here the task takes longer than the interval, so the tasks will just queue up until you run out of memory.

Comment: I agree for this scenario but some times  timer get executed once and i got two entry on server with different data at same time and it doesn't print logs in log of executing it twice at same time

Comment: @Edward are you using the same thread pool for anything else that might be choking it up?

Comment: i am using this in  service and i don't know how to check thread pool, so will u please tell me  then i'll check and let you know.